# Cannot browse from client to apache on Hyper v server

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I have a hyperv machine running on a network, I can ping the machine and RDP into it but when Apache is running I cannot browse to the site, I get a timeout error as the connection takes too long to respond.

Any ideas? Does Hyper v need to be set up properly or should I just use a different virtualiazation program?

Comment: ...firewall on the guest?

Comment: Oh man, someone thinkgs Hyper-V is unsuitable - like there is any use for any server (virtual or not) without network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Firewall needs to be configured just like any other server. Allow the port and you're good to go.